# (Progress AppBuilder) Which control can handle DB browsing automatically?

Tags: controls, openedge, progress-4gl

As mentioned before, I've recently started working for a firm, creating applications in OpenEdge Progress-4GL.

One of the basic things we're doing here is putting a fill-in field on the screen, where we can fill in the value of an entry in a table.

Let's have a look at the following table, as an example:

```
employee_name employee_number
============= ===============
    Dominique             001
         Carl             002
     Charlize             003
       Freddy             004
```

My company's fill-in field handles the following features:

Enter the name of an employee ("Carl"), and the database jumps to the corresponding tuple in the database (002).
Press "Cursor-up" and the database jumps to the tuple just above (001).
Press "Cursor-down" and the database jumps to the tuple just underneath (003).

We are currently working with OpenEdge AppBuilder Release 11.6.
As far as general OpenEdge Progress software is concerned, we are working with OpenEdge Release 11.6 as of Fri Oct 16 19:01:51 EDT 2015.

I've just found out that we are simulating simple tab pages with checkboxes and visibility properties of basic components, which is extremely outdated, I'm looking to update this way of working, and I also wonder if there are newer ways to browse in a database, instead of working with the mentioned fill-in fields.

Does anybody have an idea if there are more recent controls I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [browse widget](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/browse-widget.html) (static or dynamic), which can be associated with a query (that uses temp-tables or database tables) is the normal widget for showing data.

You can also use a [.Net grid control](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/pdsoe/data-binding-example.html) with databinding.

Comment: Next to the browse widget, there's also the DB Fields, the first one of the palette, which I can use for that purpose. (In the meantime I've learnt how to use the "VIEW-AS" in the data dictionary for similar purposes).

Comment: Yes, I overlooked your context being AppBuilder. Consider putting AppBuilder in the title of your question if you want a (legacy) AppBuilder solution versus a normal generic solution.